# Current mode boost converter design

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, boost, buck-boost

I was trying to design a current mode boost converter in CCM using a MCP1630 and the specifications of the design are as follow:

```
Vinmin=2.7V (minimum input voltage).
Vinmax=4.2V (maximum input voltage).
Vout=5V     (Output voltage).
Iout=5A     (Maximum output current).
RL=5 Ohm    (load resistor Vout/Iout).
```

I have calculated the components and they are as follow:

```
Dmin=0.16   (Minimum duty cycle)
Dmax=0.46   (Maximum duty cycle)
L=5uH       (Inductor value)
Ipeak=2.2A  (Peak current)
C=200uF     (Output capacitor)
Fc=8kH      (Crossover frequency)
```

The sense resistor is selected to be Rs=0.36 ohm, because the maximum current sense signal for MCP1630 is 0.9V (for Ipeak=2.2A Vsense=Ipeak*Rs=0.36*2.2=0.8v, we let 0.1V as a margin).

For the feedback control I have sellected a type 2 amplifier with the following components:

```
    *Divider network: Rup=Rlow=10k
    *Refrence voltage Vref=2.5V
    *C1=2.5nF
    *C2=15.6pF
    *R2=100k
```

I provide the circuit bellow:

[image]

Unfortunatly, when I simulated my circuit, I never get 5V at the output, instead I get 3.94 and the duty cycle approaches 90% and I don't know what is the reason for that failure.
Please try to figure out where I have mistaken!!

Bellow I provide you with the signals:

[image]

Comment: IRF540 needs >5V Gate drive to turn on fully. Try a logic level FET.

Comment: the MCP1630 provides 5V à its DRVR output, so I dont think that this is the problem, but I will try with another logic FET, Thanks

Comment: compute the energy into the inductor; ensure you know where that energy ends up.

Comment: I still could not troubleshoot the circuit. Please any  help  ?